# Вывести из многомерного массива

Tags: php

Имеем многомерный массив

```
$return_data = json_decode($response);
```

как вывести к примеру  Sun  7 Showers ? Что не пробую или не выводит или ошибка.
Содержание массива

```
stdClass Object ( 
[location] => stdClass Object ( 
[woeid] => 924584 
[city] => Kryvyy Rih 
[region] => Dnipropetrovsk Oblast 
[country] => Ukraine 
[lat] => 47.9063 
[long] => 33.394699 
[timezone_id] => Europe/Kiev ) 

[current_observation] => stdClass Object ( 

[wind] => stdClass Object ( 
[chill] => 17 
[direction] => 35 
[speed] => 7 ) 

[atmosphere] => stdClass Object (
[humidity] => 51 
[visibility] => 16.1
[pressure] => 999 
[rising] => 0 ) 

[astronomy] => stdClass Object ( 
[sunrise] => 6:02 am 
[sunset] => 7:33 pm ) 

[condition] => stdClass Object ( 
[text] => Showers 
[code] => 11 
[temperature] => 17 ) 

[pubDate] => 1555070400 )




 [forecasts] => Array (

 [0] => stdClass Object (
     [day] => Fri 
     [date] => 1555016400
     [low] => 8 
     [high] => 17
     [text] => Showers 
     [code] => 11 ) 

 [1] => stdClass Object (
     [day] => Sat 
     [date] => 1555102800 
     [low] => 7 
     [high] => 17
     [text] => Showers 
     [code] => 11 ) 

 [2] => stdClass Object (
     [day] => Sun 
     [date] => 1555189200 
     [low] => 7
     [high] => 14 
     [text] => Showers 
     [code] => 11 ) 
  ) )
```

Comment: `$return_data = json_decode($response, true);`

Comment: Вы имеете не массив, а объект, для того. чтобы был массив, нужно вторым аргументом функции `json_decode` выставить флаг `true`, чтобы была конвертация из объекта в массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой код:

```
 echo $return_data->forecasts[2]->day
```

Ну и т.д.

Comment: `->day` только.

Comment: @teran да, там ведь тоже object

Comment: Огромная вам благодарность )))